# Can I boot an old Windows SSD with a MacBook and install BootCamp driver?

Tags: windows, macos, boot-camp

Is it possible to boot an old Windows 10 SSD with a MacBook with macOS Mojave and then install the BootCamp Driver? I know it´s possible to install BootCamp to an external SSD but can I boot one? Or do I have to make a Backup and make a new Windows 10 install with BootCamp and then import my data?

Comment: Nobody's picked up on this one yet, but I'd say 'unlikely'. Windows doesn't like being moved to new hardware like that & can be a bit finicky about booting from an external drive at the best of times. Safest would be clean install & migrate, I'd think.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin whats the best way to migrate all Programs and all my Files?

Comment: I honestly don't know on Windows. Mac has a Migration Assistant but idk if Win has an equivalent. Acronis has a 'bare metal' restore option called Universal Restore for restoration to dissimilar hardware which I've used before to successfully move Win installs to new machines, but I've had it fail at simple things like restore to the same machine. I don't use Win enough these days to really know what to trust. Maybe try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/